# $rootScope as event aggregator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using angular-js. I have a service that need to trigger event each time something occurs. For doing it I need an object that will act as `event aggregator`.

1. Do I need to build one? Or should I use the `$rootScope`?
2. In case I should use `$rootScope`, how can I ensure that there is no event names conflicts?
3. Is it efficient to use `$rootScope` for events that don't need them to propagate to child scopes?

Comment: What do you mean by *event aggregator*? Is it the central point to broadcast events? Do you want all listeners to hook to the *event aggregator* directly?

Comment: Yes. Event aggregator is a central object which broadcast events and other objects listen to it. For example, a service need to broadcast an 'action' event, it will call vent.trigger('action'); and other objects that done vent.on('action', callback); will execute their callback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I modeled and implemented the following mechanism in a web project for tablets:

1. Define *notifications* in your services. I did not want to use the term *events* since I did not want it to be confused with *DOM events* by other developers in my team. And a semi-typed name for a notification is easier for IDE with intellisense support and for debugging. For example, I have one `Device` service that would `$broadcast(Device.Notification.OrientationDidChange)` when a tablet device's orientation is changed.
2. Use `Scope` objects to `$broadcast` or `$emit` *notifications*, depending on your need. For example,

   - For global *notifications* like the previous one, I do: `$rootScope.$broadcast(Device.Notification.OrientationDidChange)`. So all listeners can listen on their own scope without injecting `$rootScope`.
   - For *local notifications* that could possibly only affect the current scope (and its children), such as a *notification* that a scope needs to tell all its child scopes that the layout of the current controller is changed, usually I do: `scope.$broadcast(UI.Notification.NeedsLayout)`, where `UI` is a predefined service to hold UI related constants, and `scope` is the current scope.
   - For certain notifications that a child scope needs to send upwards, for example, a slider directive that tells ascendant scopes that the `rangeStart` value has changed (in addition to regular two way binding), I use: `scope.$emit(Slider.Notification.RangeStartDidChange)`, where `scope` is the current scope.
3. This approach is a bit verbose in a small project. You might want to stick to using `$rootScope.$emit(Notification)` all the time, and let all listeners to do `$rootScope.$on(Notification, callback)` to receive these notifications.
4. In some situations, you might want to define these notifications in a centralized service in order to more easily avoid name conflicts. It really based upon your project's naming convention.
5. The implementation (actual values) of these notifications may vary. I prefer using `strings`.
6. With `$broadcast` or `$emit` you can also actually pass additional arguments to the listeners, for example, `$broadcast(Notification, arg1, arg2)`... [*Angular*'s documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) is quite detailed.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast`.

1. Using `$rootScope` as event aggregator is perfectly fine unless you are triggering events outslide `digest cycle` or triggering multiple (100+)  events at the same time where some other solutions may be more appropriate .
2. One accepted practice would be to use namespacing (`namespace:event` - pattern used by `Backbone.Marionette`)
3. Use `$emit` on a child scope instead of `$broadcast` on `$rootScope` - `$emit` propagates only upwards, where `$broadcast` propagates downwards - to all children

Comment: Good answer.  Point of note: on $rootScope, $broadcast and $emit are going to do basically the samething. Since it's the "root".

Comment: @blesh I don't think that is correct, on `$rootScope`, `$emit` will trigger just there (as there isn't any level up), while `$broadcast` will propagates to every `scope` in your app (which is a performance killer).

Comment: 3. is poorly phrased. I meant to say "used $emit from a child scope instead of $broadcast on $rootScope". I wasn't specific enough.